# apc_fetchでStuck Spinlockが発生する理由

Tags: php

Apache上にmod_phpを載せてサービスを運営しているとします。この際特定のページで稀に
apc_fetchを実行した時と思われるのですが

```
PHP Fatal error:  apc_fetch() [<a href='function.apc-fetch'>function.apc-fetch</a>]
Stuck spinlock (0xXXXXXXXX) detected in ~
```

というエラーが出ることがあります。

apcのStuck spinlockが発生してしまうとApacheのResponseが悪くなってしまいサービス運用上困ってしまいます。Stuck Spinlockがでる原因は一般的に考えてどのようなことなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7年前の記事なので現状と合わないかもしれませんが、以下が適当かと思います。

[.::t3rmin4t0r::. : php/user-cache-timebomb.html](http://notmysock.org/blog/php/user-cache-timebomb.html)

記事の最後は「The only safe solution is to never call an apc_store() from a user request context.」で締め括られています。

Comment: 後継となったapcuもapcからopcode cache周りのコードを外したものなので現状でもマッチしますね。

一応補足しとくとserialize/deserializeのコストが一般的に高いのでこういうことが起こりやすいという背景があります。